# how to have last modified date of directories changed when files in directory change?

Tags: directory, settings

I am syncing files between MacOS and a remote Ubuntu server.

On Ubuntu, the date of last modification of a directory doesn't change when I store, modify or delete a file inside this directory.

On MacOS this behavior is different (and seems irrational to me): Although the directory itself stays unchanged, its "last modified" date gets changed every time when something inside this directory gets changed.

So, when I create a directory on MacOS and sync it to Ubuntu, everything is fine: both have the same date. But when I move files in one of the directories, and sync those files, the directories date on Ubuntu keeps its old value, but the date on the corresponding directory on MacOS will be changed, and then, because of this different date, my sync-programm shows differences where in fact no differences are.

I am trying to find a setting in MacOS that makes Mac-directories behave like Ubuntu-Directories, but I'm afraid, that this is not possible. So parallel to a solution on MacOS I am searching for a workaround on Ubuntu:

Is there a setting in Ubuntu, that induces it's directories to behave like their counterparts on MacOS? Which means: The directories "last modified" date should be changed every time when a new file is inserted into this directory, and when an existing file is changed or deleted.

Comment: An alternative is to make your synchronizing program check for the date stamp of files and not for directories (and let the date stamps for directories differ), if that is possible with your tool. **`rsync`** is a tool with many options, and you might find such an option.

Comment: @sudodus: I am using filezilla. When I open corresponding directories on both computers, it compares the files inside this directories. The problem is: When one of those files is a directory, it will be highlighted if the date is different. This is irritating and annoying. When I open this highlighted directory, I can see, that all files within it are equal. So in fact there is nothing to synchronize, but there still is a highlighted directory.

Comment: I don't know of any setting of the kind that you want. Maybe there is, and someone else will chip in and help you. But I think you can get around the problem by using another tool for synchronizing. I mentioned `rsync`. There is also Unison, which can be run both in graphical mode and in text mode. I use Unison in graphical mode to synchronize my **data** partition, and it has worked well for me during several years. Both `rsync` and Unison can work via ssh, like Filezilla.

Comment: Behavior on Mac and Windows seems more rational to me, which is the reason I'm looking for similar settings for Linux.